# SCOM Custom Data against a managed entity

Tags: scom

Is it possible to extend SCOM to store custom fields against a monitored/managed entity? For instance, we would like to add some additional data about each managed entity, mostly text and internal information. I didn't know if this was possible. We're going down the route of writing a custom web application to do this, but it seems like this should be possible within the tool itself. I tried searching online for this specific feature, but I kept getting links to custom alert fields, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend SCOM with custom classes that define your own attributes.

Take a look at this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh457609.aspx) on custom attributes - that should be what you're looking for.

That article includes this important guidance:

> When you create a new attribute in the Operations console, a new class
>   is created for each custom attribute that you create. Even if you
>   create multiple attributes on the same class, a new class will be
>   created for each one. Too many classes can result in excessive
>   overhead. If you create more than a few custom attributes for a class,
>   you should use another tool such as the System Center Operations
>   Manager 2007 R2 Authoring Console that will allow you to create a
>   single class with multiple attributes.

So if you want to create many new attributes - or want more flexibility such as using scripts to populate the attributes - then you should look at the options for advanced  management pack authoring.

There's an overview of the authoring tools available in [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh457569.aspx).